# I tried to make a code but it seems it return a wrong value on the output of sum

Tags: c

Here is my code written in c language, I keep on changing the code and placing the `x=a` and `y=b` in different location on the source code but it worse.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int sum, a=3, b=5, x=0, y=0;

    while(a<10){
        printf("\n%d",a);
        a+=3;
        x=a;
        if(a>10){
            goto c;
        }
    }
    c:
    while(b<10){
        printf("\n%d",b);
        b+=5;
        y=b;
        if(b>10){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    sum=x+y;
    printf("\nSum is %d", sum);

}
```

It is obvious that the sum must be 23, but it returned 22:

```
3
6
9
5
Sum is 22
```

Comment: x:12(3+3+3+3), y:10(5+5), x+y:22

Comment: You can replace the `goto` with `break`.

Comment: 'goto c;', IRTA 'go to next question'.

Comment: You don't even need x and y. You can just `sum=a+b`. As @BLUEPIXY says, the correct answer is 22. Your first while loop executes three times:  initial value 3, then +3+3+3. Your second while loop executes once:  initial value 5, then +5. a=x=12. b=y=10. So, your `sum` is 22.

Comment: how to make x=3+6+9 and y=5 to make x+y=23

Comment: Your code does not reflect what you would like to do.

Comment: @jack1: I added an answer.

Comment: The `if` conditions in the loops reflect the control conditions on the `while` loops; you don't need the `if` conditions too, and then you don't need the labels or `goto` (or `return`).  You should terminate lines of output with newlines; occasionally, it is reasonable to start a line with a newline, but finishing is important — the output may not appear until the newline is printed, or the program ends.  That doesn't matter much with this code, but it matters in bigger program.

Answer (score 0):

Look in you code, there is the answer...

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int sum, a=3, b=5, x=0, y=0;

    while(a<10){
        printf("\n%d",a);
        a+=3;
        x=a;
        if(a>10){
            goto c;
        }
    }
    c:
    while(b<10){
        printf("\n%d",b);
        b+=5;
        y=b;
        if(b>10){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    sum=x+y;
    printf("\nSum is %d", sum);

}



    While a < 10... 

before store 3 inside x, you increase a to 3 (3+3=6), then you store 6 inside x
after that, you add 3 to a (6+3=9) and store it inside x...
after that, you add 3 to a (9+3=12) and stores it inside x... 
x = 6
x = 9
x = 12
You never store 3 inside x and then you store 12, one step further

and the you go to c (goto c;), and you keep 12 inside x... 

    while b < 10... 

b = 5... but you increase in 5... then you got 10 inside b... 
And then you store it inside y... 
and then... 10 is not less than 10 (because 10 is equal to 10) you go out the loop

and then you got... 
    x = 12
+   y = 10
------------
=       22
```

And that was the explanation why you got 22 instead 23...

But here is the answer to get 23

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int sum, a=3, b=5, x=0, y=0;

    while(a<10)
    {
        printf("\n%d",a);
        x+=a; //x = x + a
        a+=3;
        if(x>10){
            goto c;
        }
    }
c:
    while(b<10)
    {
        printf("\n%d",b);
        y+=b; // y = y + b //but this run just once
        b+=5;
        if(y>10){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    sum=x+y;
    printf("\nSum is %d", sum);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comment, this will give you 3 + 6 + 9 + 5 = 23

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int sum, a=3, b=5, x=0, y=0;

    while(a<10){
        x+=a;
        a+=3;
        printf("\n%d ",x);
        if(x>10){
            goto c;
        }
    }
    c:
    while(b<10){
        y=b;
        b+=5;
        printf("\n%d",y);
        if(b>10){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    sum=x+y;
    printf("\nSum is %d", sum);

}
```